# Android, wide or multiple screens

Tags: android

I'm new to all this.  I have 2 Android Application Development books that I've read through, but I still don't understand somethings.

I was trying to make a 'flash card' type program for my daughter.  I already had images had up since I had printed them out previously.  But I can't find anyway to display them.

The closest I got was creating a Gridview with all the images listed, when I do this, I can only scroll up and down and it won't stop scrolling with the image centered.

I probably don't want a Gridview anyways since I need to be able to tap on the card to 'turn it over'.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, tell me what I should be looking for.  A different Widget, some fancy xml, or do I need to dive into 2d/3d graphics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the API Demos provided with the SDK. Look for "ImageSwitcher" demo, i think it should be a good start for what you want to do.